# how to get dictionary elements names as list

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have below dictionary and I need to extract "red" and "blue" values as list, there may be a lot more values than only these 2.

input:

```
js = {
    "accounts": {
        "red": {
            "client_id": "123",
            "client_secret": "123",
        },
        "blue": {
            "client_id": "123",
            "client_secret": "123",
        }
    }
}
```

expected output:

```
["red","blue"]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: See this: [`dict.keys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20keys#dict.keys)

Comment: @gribvirus74 thank you, it works

Comment: `list(js['accounts'])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple. There's no need to use `dict.keys()` at all...

```
js = {
    "accounts": {
        "red": {
            "client_id": "123",
            "client_secret": "123",
        },
        "blue": {
            "client_id": "123",
            "client_secret": "123",
        },
        "green": {
            "client_id": "123",
            "client_secret": "123",
        }
    }
}

print (list(js["accounts"]))
```

Output:

```
['red', 'blue', 'green']
```

Comment: you don't need the `.keys` method at all, you can just remove it and use `list(js['aacounts']))`